# Diagnose app crashing on startup in specific machines?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

Recently i upgraded from Delphi 2007 to 10.3.3 . The same app when compiled with 10.3.3 will crash at startup, but only in some machines ; in my environment i could not simulate the problem but some of my customers are having this issue. If i compile the same app in D2007, the error won't happen so i assume is something related to the new Delphi version.

The error message is this below and after this, the app will close. The message is too generic, what can i do to at least try to identify what is causing the crash ?

Here is what i tried : in the main form of my application, i went to the FormCreate event and put a *showmessage('stop');* on the first line, but the crash happens before this.

I know this is a hard question, but i'm seeking for suggestions to at least look in some direction, so please help !

Thanks in advance.

[image]

UPDATE : Here is Eureka Log trace :

[image]

Comment: Well, read of address 00000000 means it's trying to read from a nil pointer.

Comment: If the crash happens before the creation of your main form, then it's likely to occur in the `initialization` section of some unit, which is a pain in the @$$ to track down and debug.

Comment: I would go with madExcept. it will help you determine exactly where the exception is.

Comment: You need a stacktrace, MadExcept or Eurekalog should be helpful in your case

Comment: Unfortunately, it is impossible for us to find the problem. You need to debug the application. Remove one part at a time, step through initialization sections, class constructors, and `TForm.OnCreate` handlers, etc.

Comment: @delphirules: if you cannot reproduce it on your system; there is always the possibility to do [remote debugging](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Overview_of_Remote_Debugging)

Comment: Here is what Eureka Log gives me : Datasnap.DBClient TCustomClientDataSet / Internal check

Comment: I just updated the question with EurekaLog trace, any clues ?

Comment: Are you using `MidasLib` in your project? If not, do you have `MIDAS.dll` accessible to your app? Is it the correct DLL version?

Comment: I use the DLL, not midaslib, and yes, the correct version

Answer (score 1):

After install EurekaLog, i could find the problem was related to Datasnap. Here is what i did that fixed the issue, hopefully will help somebody.

The library midas.dll was already present in the same folder of the app. I then copied midas.dll to c:\windows\syswow64 and run the command below in prompt with Admin rights :

```
c:\windows\syswow64\regsvr32 midas.dll
```

After that the app runs fine.

Can somebody explains why this was needed ?

Comment: The start-up code of the DSIntf unit contains a function CheckDBClient which uses a call to the system registry to read the location where Midas.Lib is *supposed* to be located.

Comment: FWIW, we've never had to register it, so long as it resides in the same directory as the executable. Personally, I highly frown on the practice of applications dumping such things into the system folder(s).

Comment: @JerryDodge, yes i don't like it either, but this was the way to fix. I'll try to use Midaslib instead from now on

Comment: @JerryDodge:  Well, I'm not sure why the OP thought it necessary to copy Midas.Lib to the SysWow64 folder (apart from the usual sledgehammer to crack a walnut reason) - he could have left it where it was and specified the path to it in the name fed to RegSvr32.

Comment: @MartynA In general, my point is that I've never had to use `regsvr32` for it. We just keep it in our executable directory to be found automatically.

Comment: @MartynA I tried to run revsvr32 with midas.dll in the same path of the app, and this did not work. The problem only fixed when i copied midas.dll to syswow64 and registered it in this folder.  I have no idea why...

Comment: @JerryDodge In my personal experience with Datasnap (more than a decade), somehow there are some machines that only put midas.dll in app's folder is not enough. For any reason is necessary to run regsvr32, i don't know why, but i this happens sometimes.